# Illustrator CC - Creating an object mosaic but ignore transparent pixels?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I decided that converting my pixel images to vector through Inkscape was a lot of work and it couldn't convert 16px images without being resized first. So I figured out I could use the "Create Object Mosaic" feature in Illustrator, it does exactly what I want.. The only problem is that it creates a 16x16 grid no matter what, and all the transparent pixels are filled in with white.

Is there any way I can set it to ignore the transparent pixels in the image? Or a better way of doing it?

Here's some visuals, starting with the options I use:

[image: Settings]

What it outputs:

[image: Output Paths]

What I have to delete each time:

[image: Transparent Pixels]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Select one of the blocks:

[image]

2. Menu... Select → Same → Fill Color

[image]

3. Result, ready for you to delete or change color or whatever:

[image]

## Alternative Method

As an alternative you can `Image Trace` and find the preset that works for you. In this case `High Fidelity Photo` then click the `Expand` button next to the dropdown menu in the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Much faster than selecting them individually.

Comment: Sure thing you can also use the Image Trace feature, I just edited to show you. But it's not quite as crisp, might work for you though and would be even faster. @Winter

Comment: I'll give Image Trace a try, but it's never been cooperative with me in the past. In your alternative image, did you increase the size of the original image?

Comment: In both of them I increased the size... namely because I just dropped your zoomed in screenshot into photoshop, cropped around it real quick, then pasted that into illustrator. @Winter